# Use crystal ball to hide bristle, like a rake

Tags: cryptic-clues

> Use crystal ball to hide bristle, like a rake?

I'm quite sure the answer is 'scrawny' but cannot work out why.

Comment: Could you add more information (source, relevant portion of puzzle, why you think that is answer)?

Comment: @Jason It seems that this puzzle originated from http://www.danword.com/crossword/Use_a_crystal_ball_to_hide_bristle_like_a_rake_w65r but I am not 100% sure

Answer (score 4):

> Use crystal ball ([SCRY](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scry)) to hide (to contain) bristle ([AWN](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awn)), like a [rake](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/thin+as+a+rake)? (SCRAWNY)

Comment: Just beat me to the post on this one +1. I agree 100%